# The inequality for the weak of $L^p$,where $p\in(0,1)$

Tags: proof-verification, harmonic-analysis

There is a quite interesting problem for me to deal with it :

Let $f_1,f_2,...,f_N$ be in $L^{p,\infty}(X,\mu)$ which is the space of weak $L^p(X,\mu)$

Prove that for $0< p< 1$ we have 
$$\bigg\lVert\sum_{k=1}^{N} f_k\bigg\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}\leq N^{\frac{1}{p}}\,\sum_{k=1}^{N}\lVert f_k\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}$$

*proof :*

Use the notation $\omega_{|f_k\,|}(\alpha)=\bigg|\{x\in X:|f_k(x)|>\alpha\}\bigg|$.

For each $\alpha>0$ , $\bigg\{x\in X :|f_{1}(x)+\cdots+f_{N}(x)|>\alpha\bigg\}\subseteq\displaystyle\bigcup_{k=1}^{N}\bigg\{x\in X:|f_{k}(x)|>\dfrac{\alpha}{N}\bigg\}$

Then,one has

\begin{align*}
\omega_{|f_{1}+\cdots+f_{N}|}(\alpha)&=\bigg|\bigg\{x\in X:|f_{1}(x)+\cdots+f_{N}(x)|>\alpha\bigg\}\bigg|\\
&\leq\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left|\left\{x\in X:|f_{k}(x)|>\frac{\alpha}{N}\right\}\right|\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\omega_{|f_{k}|}\bigg(\frac{\alpha}{N}\bigg)
\end{align*}

Whence,for every $\alpha>0$
\begin{align*}
\alpha^p\omega_{|f_{1}+\cdots+f_{N}|}(\alpha)&\leq N^p\dfrac{\alpha^p}{N^p}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\omega_{|f_{k}|}\bigg(\frac{\alpha}{N}\bigg)\\
&=N^p\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{\alpha^{p}}{N^{p}}\omega_{|f_{k}|}\bigg(\frac{\alpha}{N}\bigg)\\
&\leq N^p\sum_{k=1}^{N}\sup\bigg\{\frac{\alpha^{p}}{N^{p}}\omega_{|f_{k}|}\bigg(\frac{\alpha}{N}\bigg):\alpha>0\bigg\}\\
&\leq N^p\sum_{k=1}^{N}\lVert f_k\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}^{p}
\end{align*}

Now when $\delta\in [1,\infty)$ use the face that $\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{N} a_k\bigg)^\delta\leq N^{\delta-1}\sum_{k=1}^{N} a^\delta_k\,$ for each $a_k\in\mathbb{R_{>0}}$

Thus,
\begin{align*}
\alpha\bigg(\omega_{|f_{1}+\cdots+f_{N}|}(\alpha)\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}
&\leq N\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{N}\lVert f_k\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}^{p}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}\\
&\leq N\cdot N^{(\frac{1}{p}-1)}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\lVert f_k\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}\\
&=N^{\frac{1}{p}}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\lVert f_k\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}} 
\end{align*}
Then,

$$\bigg\lVert\sum_{k=1}^{N} f_k\bigg\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}=\sup\bigg\{\alpha\bigg(\omega_{|f_{1}+\cdots+f_{N}|}(\alpha)\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}:\alpha>0\bigg\}\leq N^{\frac{1}{p}}\,\sum_{k=1}^{N}\lVert f_k\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}$$

If you have the time,please checking my working for validity with me and any advice will appreciate.Thanks for patiently reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is overall good. Perhaps one line can be sharpen like the following:

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\alpha^{p}}{N^{p}}\omega_{|f_{k}|}\left(\dfrac{\alpha}{N}\right)\leq\sup\{\alpha^{p}\omega_{|f_{k}|}(\alpha): \alpha>0\}=\|f_{k}\|_{L^{p,\infty}}^{p}.
\end{align*}